# How do I build the database for my P2P rental marketplace?

Tags: python, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I'm self-teaching programming through the plethora of online resources to build a startup idea I've had for awhile now. Currently, I'm using the SaaS platform at sharetribe.com for my business but I'm trying to build my own platform as share tribe does not cater to the many options I'd like to have available to my users.

I'm try to setup the database at this time and I'm currently working on the architecture. I plan to use MySQL for my database.

The website will feature an online inventory management system where users can track all their items, update availability, pricing, delivery, payments, analytical tools, etc. This is so the user can easily monitor their current items, create new listings, etc. so it creates more of a "business" feel for the users.

Here is a simple explanation of the work flow. Users will create their profile having access to rent or rent out their items. Once their account is created they can search listing based on the category, subcategory, location, price, etc. When rental is placed, the user will request the rental at specified time, once approved, the rental process will begin.

My question is how should I set up the infrastructure/architecture for the database? I have this as my general workings but I know I'm missing a lot of queries and criteria to suit the application.

User queries:
-user_ID
-name
-email
-username
-encrypted_password
-location
-social_media
-age
-photo

Product queries:
-item_ID
-user_ID
-category_ID
-subcategory_ID
-price
-description
-availability
-delivery_option

As you can see, I'm new to this but as many of the resources I've used for my research, all have said the best way to learn is to do. I'm probably taking on a bigger project that I should for my beginning stages but there will be plenty of mistakes made that will assist my learning.

Any and all recommendations and assistance are appreciated.

For general knowledge, I intend to utilize Rails as my server language. If you recommend Python/Django over Ruby/Rails, could you please explain why this would be more beneficial to me?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is outside of the scope for StackOverflow in that it's **too broad** and **asks for a recommendation**. You'd best start familiarizing yourself with a technology of choice first. Whichever that is; there's a lot of info regarding Rails vs. Django. Once you hit specific problems with this technology you can't resolve by using a search engine, then by all means, ask StackOverflow. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This is really a complex question and there is no quick solution. What you should do is stick to Agile development method, as many Rails developers do. It means that you shouldn't plan the whole DB structure in the very beginning. Instead you should develop step by step, one feature after another. Just outline the very essential features of your future application, such features that your application cannot exist without. This will be your MVP. It will not require complex planning and designing, because you're not going to implement all the features, but only those that you really need. This approach will also take off load from your brain and let you concentrate on development. After building an MVP, you can easily continue adding one feature after another, also without planning far ahead.

You can also use such project management tools as PivotalTracker, Trello etc. These are a huge help. And you can read Agile Development with Rails 4, it will give you a good understanding on how the development on Rails usually goes on.

If you're not confident in building models, relations, associations, then just read this thing http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html You need to understand all these relation types, like has_many, belongs_to, has_one etc. After that it'll be much easier for you to build models and relations in mind.

As to Python/Django vs Ruby/Rails there is no much difference. These are just tools that do the same job. It's just a matter of taste which one to choose.
But Rails is usually a better fit for such people like you, who are more entrepreneurs than programmers. It allows you to build a working application, even if you're not a hacker. Django is not like this, it's more for programmers than for entrepreneurs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your feedback is informative and helpful. I realize I may be getting to far ahead of myself. I've spent several hours researching and using code academy and code school to learn the basics of syntax but I've felt like something was missing the whole time which has led me to jump right in. I will definitely take your advice and check out the rubyonrails guides to further my learning. One last question, do you have any recommendations on where I can "connect" with people just starting out learning this stuff. Having someone to work with would make it easier I feel.

Comment: The whole guides.rubyonrails.org is extremely useful, because it contains all the information about Rails you need to know to build applications. You can refer to it any time when you come across any difficulty.
As to communities, I'm not really sure. I think there should be communities around online courses, like codeacademy and codeschool. Also try courses on teamtreehouse.com, they have members-only forums. I also think you can find someone to cooperate with on www.reddit.com/r/ruby/ Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Learn a good book on software development methodologies before you get into this . Then read some simple tutorial online on mysql . Then it will be a lot more easy to do this .